# microsoft.speech synthesizer Speak command hangs

Tags: c#, synthesizer

I have been using Microsoft.Speech synthesizer for years on different PCs and different versions of Windows.  I am trying to set up the development and support environment on a new Windows 10 PC and I can't get spsynthesizer to work correctly.  I have downloaded the Microsoft SDK5.1 and the voices twice now to make sure nothing was corrupted.  I have stepped through each line of code with the debugger and everything works as expected until the call to spsynthesizer.speak...the call never speaks and never returns to the program.  I have tried executing as x86, x64 and AnyCPU and I have a reference entry to Microsoft.Speech.

Any suggestions?  Here is the simple C# test application.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Speech.Synthesis;
namespace test_text_to_speech
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Microsoft.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer spsynthesizer = new Microsoft.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer();
        System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<Microsoft.Speech.Synthesis.InstalledVoice> myvoices;
        myvoices = spsynthesizer.GetInstalledVoices();
        spsynthesizer.SelectVoice(myvoices[0].VoiceInfo.Name); //Invoke the one which you want
        spsynthesizer.Volume = 100; // Can be 1 - 100
        spsynthesizer.Rate = 1; // can be 1 - 10 
        spsynthesizer.SetOutputToDefaultAudioDevice();

        PromptBuilder Thanks = new PromptBuilder();
            Thanks.AppendSsmlMarkup("<voice xml:lang=\"en-US\">");
        Thanks.StartStyle(new PromptStyle(PromptEmphasis.Strong));
            Thanks.AppendText("Hello World");
        Thanks.EndStyle();
        Thanks.AppendSsmlMarkup("</voice>");

        spsynthesizer.Speak(Thanks);
        spsynthesizer.Speak("try with no markup");

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Open a Connect and attach your repro. They're usually good about getting back within a couple days.

Comment: Thanks Will.  I have worked with Microsoft on issues in the past and they can usually come up with an answer (not always) but it does indeed take days.  I use Stackoverflow a lot and I was hopeful that someone else had run into this issue in the past and might have a solution.  But your suggestion is good and I will make an inquiry into Microsoft.

Comment: I found the issue in my particular situation to be the audio driver getting corrupted when swapping between the "System" and "Microsoft" speech components under Windows 10.  I became suspicious when I found that I had also lost all of the standard Windows "sounds" with different actions.I have been able to duplicate the problem which is resolved by running the Audio repair tool.  Once the repair is completed, the voices again work

Comment: Good for you. You can add that as an answer below and, after the required wait, mark it as correct. That may seem strange, but that's the way we handle situations like this.